# Passing credentials from aws-sdk-sts' assume_role to aws_config in Rust

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-sts, aws-sdk-rust

I am trying to get information on CodePipeline via the Rust `aws-sdk-codepipeline`.

When using my default environment, everything work like a charm:

```
use aws_sdk_codepipeline as codepipeline;

main() {
   let config = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
   let client = codepipeline::Client::new(&config);

   ...
 }
```

I am able to run `client.list_pipelines()`, etc.. and get the data I need. However, I also need to get information on other accounts as well.  This is where I turned to `aws-sdk-sts` to use `assume_role`.

I have the following code that successfully accomplished that:

```
use aws_sdk_sts as sts;

main() {
    let assumed_role_output = sts::Client::new(&aws_config::load_from_env().await)
        .assume_role()
        .role_arn("arn:aws:iam::012345678910:role/dev-ops-role")
        .role_session_name("devops")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();

     let credentials = assumed_role_output.credentials().unwrap();
```

This gives me the `&Credentials`, but where I am stumped is how to get said credentials into the `aws_config` so it can be used to create a CodePipeline `Client` for the assumed role.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-rust/latest/dg/rust_sts_code_examples.html), I came up with the following function to return a config:

```
async fn assume_role(config: &SdkConfig, role_name: String, session_name: String) -> SdkConfig {
    match config.credentials_provider() {
        Some(credential) => {
            let provider = aws_config::sts::AssumeRoleProvider::builder(role_name)
                .region(Region::from_static("us-east-1"))
                .session_name(session_name)
                .build(credential.clone());
            let local_config = aws_config::from_env()
                .credentials_provider(provider)
                .load()
                .await;
            Some(local_config)
        }
        None => None,
    }
    .unwrap()
```